# Finding Range of: $y=\log_e(3-2x)/\sqrt{x+1}$?

Tags: calculus

This is from Calculus I test, that I failed to solve correctly. This really bugs me, because for `Solve[y == Log[E, 3 - 2x] / Sqrt[x + 1], x]`, the Mathematica is telling me that: "The equations appear to involve the variables to be solved for in an essentially non-algebraic way.".

[image]

I assume that the answer is $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just observe that at $\lim_{x\to -1^+} y(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 3/2^-} y(x) = -\infty$ and $y(x)$ is continuous on $x \in (-1, 3/2)$. Therefore the range is indeed $(-\infty,\infty)$.